# Automating Account Creation

Tags: systemd, sysadmin, gcp, okta

I’ll try to be brief.

The current situation:
If we have new hires, the HR will share the names with the IT department to create emails for them and give them access to OSS app (OKTA) that we’re using and there will be the basic system they will need. ex; ticketing system - HR system - slack - zoom

The idea:
We want to automate this process. Maybe integrating OSS with our data warehouse and set a trigger that whenever we have a new hire it will create the account automatically.
And based on the possibility level the access permission will be different: Admin - viewr - .. etc
And will also give access to different systems based on the department. Ex. if the employee is in marketing then they’ll have access to Hubspot but if they’re in Software engineering then they’ll have access to Github.

Is it possible? if yes, what are the tools that will help me to achieve my goal? and if you can suggest resources to take look at before start planning and implementing

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick check on the okta documentation, leads me to their workflow automation. Okta Workflow Automation (OWA) is a platform provided by Okta that allows organizations to automate various identity-related processes and workflows. It is designed to streamline and enhance the management of user identities, access, and permissions across different applications and systems